# Loopin through directories subfolder and save result to other directory in subfolders in R

Tags: r, loops, subdirectory

In R I am looping through a folder and load netCDF files in a raster stack. Then I do my calculations and save the results into another folder in a different directory as multi band tiff.

The problem is, I have several folders with several netCDF files and I like to make the code more efficient. 
1.) Looping through subfolders in the directory and load cetCDF files
2.) Looping through subfolders in the output directory and save the results to disc

What could be an efficient way for doing this? Maybe a function?
I guess it is not so complicated, however I am a bit confused with too much for loops...

I atached a working example of what I've done now.

```
files<- list.files(path= paste(wd,"/nc_in/tmax_rcp85/", sep=""), pattern = 'nc$', full.names=TRUE)

# loop through netCDF files and create a raster stack
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  ras<- stack(files[i])
  print(ras)

  outnam<- basename(files[[i]]) # generate output name
  outnam<- sub('\\.nc$', '', outnam)

  results<- stack() # create temp stack of results

  #loop through raster stack and downscale monthly mean averages
  for (r in 1:nlayers(ras)){

    # doing some stuff with each raster in the satck

    # update results temp raster stack
    results <- stack(results, downscale)

  }

  # save downscaled rster stack to disc
  writeRaster(results, file=paste0(getwd(),"/ds_results/tmax_rcp85_ds/",sub('\\.nc$', '', outnam),"_ds",".tif", sep = ""), options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
  rm(results) # clear temp stack of results

}
removeTmpFiles(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using `recursive=T` within `list.files()`
Then I saved the resulting Tiff into the same directory including some reference information...

```
files<- list.files(path= paste(wd,"/nc_in/", sep=""), pattern = 'nc$', full.names=TRUE, recursive=T)

# loop through netCDF files and create a raster stack
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  ras<- stack(files[i])
  print(ras)

  outnam<- basename(files[[i]]) # generate output name
  outnam<- sub('\\.nc$', '', outnam)

  outdir <- dirname(files[[i]])
  Split <- strsplit(outdir, "//")
  lDir<- Split[[1]][length(Split[[1]])]

  results<- stack() # create tem stack of results

  #loop through raster stack and downscale monthly mean averages
  for (r in 1:nlayers(ras)){

    # doing some stuff with each raster in the satck


    # update results raster stack
    results <- stack(results, downscale)

  }

  print(paste("Writing multi band GeoTiff: ", outnam, "to:"))
  print(paste0(dirname(files[[i]]),'/', lDir,"_", sub('\\.nc$', '', outnam),"_ds",".tif", sep = ""))

  # save downscaled rster stack to disc
  writeRaster(results, file=paste0(dirname(files[[i]]),'/', lDir,"_", sub('\\.nc$', '', outnam),"_ds",".tif", sep = ""), options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
  rm(results) # clear temp stack of results

}
removeTmpFiles(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions

```
fin <- list.files(path= "/nc_in/tmax_rcp85/", pattern = 'nc$', full.names=TRUE)
fout <- sub("/nc_in/", "/ds_results/", sub('\\.nc$', '.tif', fin)) 
# create output directories if they do not exist
x <- lapply(fout, function(i) dir.create(dirname(i), FALSE, TRUE))


downscale <- function(x) {
    # add your code here
    return(x)
}


for (i in 1:length(fin)){
    s <- stack(fin[i])
    for (j in 1:nlayers(s)){
        s[[j]] <- downscale(s[[j]])
    }
    writeRaster(s, file=fout[i], options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)
}
```